# C# multi-threading code review

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Is it important that I lock around the queue?

```
public abstract class ExpiringCache<TKey,TValue> : IDisposable 
{
    protected readonly object locker = new object();

    protected readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> cache =
        new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    private readonly Queue<KeyValuePair<TKey, long>> queue =
        new Queue<KeyValuePair<TKey, long>>();

    private volatile bool dispose;

    private readonly Thread cleaningThread;

    private readonly long lifeSpanTicks;

    public ExpiringCache(TimeSpan lifeSpan)
    {
        // Validate lifeSpan

        if (lifeSpan.Ticks == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException
                ("lifeSpan", "Must be greater than zero.");
        }

        this.lifeSpanTicks = lifeSpan.Ticks;

        // Begin expiring expired items

        this.cleaningThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (!this.dispose)
            {
                this.RemoveExpired();
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        });

        this.cleaningThread.Start();
    }

    private void RemoveExpired()
    {
        if (this.queue.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        var pair = this.queue.Peek();

        if (pair.Value >= DateTime.Now.Ticks)
        {
            lock (this.locker)
            {
                this.cache.Remove(pair.Key);
            }

            this.queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(TKey key)
    {
        lock (this.locker)
        {
            return this.cache.ContainsKey(key);
        }
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        lock (this.locker)
        {
            this.cache.Add(key, value);
        }

        this.queue.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<TKey, long>
            (key, DateTime.Now.Ticks + this.lifeSpanTicks));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.dispose = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using WeakReferences to let the GC handle object death?

Comment: Is anything ever retrieved from the cache?

Comment: About the missing Get() method, we should just suppose that there are more methods than this, to retrieve items, but the OP didn't think it was useful to show them. Or they are used in a subclass, because they are declared protected. Either way, it's not part of the problem.

Comment: @DonkeyMaster I disagree, if this is a code review, then all the code and how the class is meant to be used and derived from is of importance.

Answer (score 6):

It's not enough to lock on just the Contains method, for example.  See this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/02/16/a-more-usable-thread-safe-collection.aspx

Basically, you need re-think the classic Queue API and use methods like `DequeueIfContains()` rather than a simple `Contains()` + `Dequeue()`, so that the same lock applies both to the `Contains` check and the `Dequeue` operation.

Comment: Joel while I don't disagree with what you say, the queue appears to be only for cleanup. There is no Get() method in the code to retrieve items from the cache, just a Contains() to see if they're in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You could use: [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)  and [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8). They are built into C# .Net 4.0 onwards.

Comment: From .Net 4.0 onward